# Set State in a loop React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state

I have some props in the form of an array of objects that I am using to update my "items" state. I am able to loop through the objects and build objects containing the "product_id" and the "quantity". When I just console.log I can see the correct data, however when I try to update the state I get the error `"Too many re-renders, react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite-loop."`

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState(
    {
      product_id: 93,
      quantity: 2,
    },
    {
      product_id: 22,
      variation_id: 23,
      quantity: 1,
    },
  );
  const cart = props.cart;
  Object.keys(cart).forEach(function (key) {
    const prod = {
      product_id: cart[key].id,
      quantity: cart[key].quantity,
    };
    setItems((currentItems) => {
      return {prod, ...currentItems};
    });
  });
```

Edit
My cart props is pulled from redux using the following code

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    cart: state.cart,
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Checkout);
```

The problem is that this prop has more attributes than just the quantity and id that I need.

Comment: What is the value being passed in as the cart prop?

Comment: When you are doing a setState, your component will then pretender, which will result in retriggering your forEach loop which will to a setState which will trigger a rerender and so on. You could wrap that forEach in a useEffect (which has callback and dependencies as params). If you pass an empty array as dependencies it will only happen once.

Comment: Why you setting the state and not just rendering with the prop values?

Comment: The cart prop uses a redux prop and MapStateToProp function. I can't just render it to the state because it has additional data that I don't need. I just need to pull the id and quantity from it.

Comment: You cannot call `setItems()` in component's global level. Wrap the state-updating code inside of a function, and then call that function based on an event (such as `onClick`, `onChange`, or something like). Moreover, it is not a good idea to update the state inside `forEach`. Just loop through the array and in the end update the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the state again and again in a loop. Rather, just loop on the array, get the items and finally set the state

```
   const [items, setItems] = React.useState(
    {
      product_id: 93,
      quantity: 2
    },
    {
      product_id: 22,
      variation_id: 23,
      quantity: 1
    }
  );

  const { cart } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    const products = Object.entries(cart).map(([key, { id, quantity }]) => ({
      product_id: id,
      quantity: quantity
    }));
    setItems(currentItems => ({ ...products, ...currentItems }));
  }, [cart]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array or an object as the state. you are passing two separate objects to useState, wrap them in an object with proper keys. or use an array.

```
it seems you have forgotten to add a wrap your initial object inside curly braces.  

const [items, setItems] = useState([
  {
    product_id: 93,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    product_id: 22,
    variation_id: 23,
    quantity: 1,
  },
]);
```

then

```
return [prod, ...currentItems];
```

as a suggestion:
it's better to make new objects and set them in the state all at once.

```
const objectsToAdd = Object.values(cart).map(function (cartItem) {
  return {
    product_id: cartItem.id,
    quantity: cartItem.quantity,
  };
});

setItems((currentItems) => {
  return [...objectsToAdd, ...currentItems];
})
```